# Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 for broser

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so i have read the other people's entries with this problem and mine is just not working . . . can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<form method="post" action="carentry.php">
Car Year: <input type="text" name="year"><br>
Car Make: <input type="text" name="make"><br>
Car Model: <input type="text" name="model"><br>
Stock #: <input type="text" name="stock"><br>
Price: <input type="text" name="price"><br>
Description: <br><textarea cols="30" rows="15" name="description"></textarea><br>
Pics:<br><textarea cols="30" rows="15" name="pics"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<$con=mysqli_connect("##","##","##","##");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO ford_man (year, make, model, stock, price, description, pics)
VALUES('$_POST[year]','$_POST[make]','$_POST[model]','$_POST[stock]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[pics]','".addslashes($_POST['description'])."','".addslashes($_POST['price'])."','".addslashes($_POST['year'])."','".addslashes($_POST['make'])."','".addslashes($_POST['model'])."','".addslashes($_POST['stock'])."','".addslashes($_POST['pics'])."')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And here's my table: 
     (link b/c i don't have a 10 rating yet) - https://www.havikmarketing.com/images/table.png

Answer (score 2):

Youre trying to insert too many values. Here are your columns

```
(year, make, model, stock, price, description, pics)
```

7 columns.

Here are your values

```
'$_POST[year]','$_POST[make]','$_POST[model]','$_POST[stock]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[pics]','".addslashes($_POST['description'])."','".addslashes($_POST['price'])."','".addslashes($_POST['year'])."','".addslashes($_POST['make'])."','".addslashes($_POST['model'])."','".addslashes($_POST['stock'])."','".addslashes($_POST['pics'])."'
```

14 values. After the 7th, MySQL doesnt know what to do with the rest of the values, so it's telling you "Column count doesn't match value count."

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$_POST` value twice for the every column. Use one column value per each.

`$_POST[year]` and `addslashes($_POST['year'])` in your query. Use any one from that values.

Try this query,

```
$sql="INSERT INTO ford_man (year, make, model, stock, price, description, pics)
VALUES('".addslashes($_POST['year'])."','".addslashes($_POST['make'])."','".addslashes($_POST['model'])."','".addslashes($_POST['stock'])."','".addslashes($_POST['price'])."','".addslashes($_POST['description'])."','".addslashes($_POST['pics'])."')";
```